# Sorting a nested json in apex

Tags: apex

I'm writing a code wherein I need to sort the data based on a field, but I'm confused on how I can use the `comparable` on the nested JSON. Also, I'm generating apex using apex2json tool.

Here is my (pseudo)code.

```
public class Appts {
    public static void getAppts(){
    String data= "{\n  \"appointmentData\": {\n    \"appointment\": [\n      {\n        \"name\": \"Jane Doe\",\n        \"phone\": \"888-555-1212\",\n        \"time\": \"19:25:00\"\n      }\n    ],\n    \"apointment\": [\n      {\n        \"name\": \"Justin Doe\",\n        \"phone\": \"877-123-1212\",\n        \"relationship\": \"parent\",\n        \"time\": \"16:00:00\"\n      },\n      {\n        \"name\": \"Justin Doe\",\n        \"phone\": \"877-123-1212\",\n        \"relationship\": \"parent\",\n        \"time\": \"16:00:00\"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}";  //this comes from callout
    
    JSON2Apex em = JSON2Apex.parse(data); 
    List<em.appointment> retList = em.appointment;  //I want this to be sorted 
    }
 }
```

Please let me know how I can do the inner sorting

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In your `em.appointment` class you need to do two things:

1. `Appointment` needs to implement [`Comparable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_comparable.htm)
2. You need to define a `compareTo` method and call `sort` on your list.

```java
public class Appointment implements Comparable

    public String name;
    public String phone;
    public String relationship;
    public Datetime time;

    public Appointment() {
        //... constructor
    }

    // defines how Appointments are sorted.
    global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        Appointment compareToAppt = (Appointment)compareTo;

        if (id == compareToAppt.name) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (id > compareToAppt.name) {
            return 1;
        }

        return -1;        
    }
}
```

I used "name" as the example field here, but if you wanted to use "time" instead (or a combination of fields) you would change the logic inside of `compareTo`.

Now that `Appointment` has defined rules on sorting, you can now sort a list of them.

```java
JSON2Apex em = JSON2Apex.parse(data); 
List<em.appointment> retList = em.appointment;  //_I want this to be sorted_
retList.sort(); // this sorts the list
```

Comment: Thanks for this @nbrown. But my issue here is this `Appointment` is nested in JSON2Apex class

Comment: You can edit the inner class inside of `JSON2Apex` or even extract it out into its own class.

Answer (score 0):

In short, if you want to use the *.sort()* in a List<**X**>, then **X** needs to be a **class** that implements the *Comparable* interface.

So basically, in this case, your class **Em.Appointment** is the one that should implement the Comparable interface. Implementing the interface will force the Em.Appointment class to have a compareTo() method which defines the ordering for the different instances of the class based on the value it returns (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_comparable.htm#apex_System_Comparable_compareTo). As per the documentation:

- 0 if this instance and objectToCompareTo are equal
- Greater than 0 if this instance is greater than objectToCompareTo
- Less than 0 if this instance is less than objectToCompareTo

You can check the example that it's in the Documentation to see an implementation of the compareTo() method. In your case, if you would like to order based on Name, you would do something like this based on the properties that I see in the JSON that you've shared:

```
global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
    Em.Appointment compareToAppointment = (Em.Appointment)compareTo;
    if (this.name == compareToAppointment.name) return 0;
    if (this.name > compareToAppointment.name) return 1;
    return -1;        
}
```

If you don't have access to the Em.Appointment class, then you could do some workaround and create your own class that has the properties that you need to perform the comparison and convert from a List<Em.Appointment> to a List and implement the Comparable interface in YourClass. Then you can use the sort() method on the List and, once it's sorted, you can convert it back to a List<Em.Appointment>.